# How to get dynamic variable class name in PHP?

Tags: php

```
class CLASS_A{}
$classA = 'CLASS_A';
var_dump(class_exists($classA::class)); //not works
```

Any idea to get the class name via variable?

Comment: If you don't care about namespaces, `var_dump(class_exists($classA));` :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use reflection for that:

```
class CLASS_A{}
$classA = 'CLASS_A';

$c = new \ReflectionClass($classA);
var_dump($c->getName());
```

References:

- [The `ReflectionClass` class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionclass.php)
- [`ReflectionClass::getName`](http://php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.getname.php)

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is the class name, you can simply use the get_class function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-class.php

```
class test{}
$obj = new test;
echo get_class($obj); // Will echo test
```

If you need to get more info, use reflection (see zerkms's answer)

Comment: OP has their class name in a variable. And then, for an arbitrary class, how do you know the constructor parameters? What about possible constructor side-effects?

Comment: So he has the class name in a variable and he wants the class name? Hmmm...

Comment: Regarding your edit, yes that would be an issue in general. However, I extrapolated from his question and assumed that he already has an object somewhere in his code and wants to get the class name.

Comment: One possible use case I can think of, is normalisation: https://3v4l.org/hlN5t Other than that, it's an odd question indeed.

Comment: It really is :P